# Prove that $\mathsf{T}$ is a completely positive transformation and $2\leq \|\mathsf{T}(v)\| \leq 7$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathsf{T}$ be a linear transformation in a internal product space $\textsf{V}$, such that
$$\mathsf{TT^*} = 9\,\textsf{T}-14\,\mathsf{I_V}$$
Prove that $\textsf{T}$ is a completely positive transformation and that:
$$2\leq \|\mathsf{T}(v)\| \leq 7 \quad \text{ for all } v\in \textsf{V} \textrm{ s.t. } \| v \|=1$$

Comment: You keep posting what must be homework problems. Welcome to MSE, but please learn to use MathJax *and*, most important, show your effort. Show what you've tried and ask specifically about what you're confused about. Don't expect us to just post answers for your homework.

Comment: Yes, these are homework-kind problems from Israel's Open University. I know because I'm a lecturer there...:)

Answer (score 0):

First,

$$TT^*=9T-14I\implies T=\frac19\left(TT^*+14I\right)\implies T^*=\frac19\left(TT^*+14I\right)^*=$$

$$=\frac19\left(\left(TT^*\right)^*+\left(14I\right)^*\right)=\frac19\left(TT^*+14I\right)=T\implies T=T^*$$

so $\;T\;$ is Hermitian and it thus fulfills

$$TT^*=T^2=9T-14I\implies T^2-9T+14I=0\implies T$$

is a zero of the polynomial $\;x^2-9x+14=(x-7)(x-2)\;$ .

Choose now a special **orthonormal** basis...and finish the argument.